# FileWriter may or may not be creating file?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app for my Kindle Fire, and I'm just trying to test writing a file, and opening it up again for now. The saving process APPEARS to be working fine, but whenever I try to press the load button, it throws a `FileNotFoundExeception` and a subsequent `NullPointerExeception` when I try to use it.

I say it appears to be working fine because I can't actually view the directory on my kindle, there's just no errors thrown when I press the save button. The directory is listed as `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/portalboat.concept/files/BLUH.txt`, but as soon as I click on the Android folder in that `/mnt/sdcard` directory, it just redirects me to `/sdcard/Android`, not `/mnt/sdcard/Android`. There's nothing there in the complete directory I can view, but I'm not sure if it's the same one.

I've run `mkdirs()` and `createNewFile(),` and there's no errors being thrown, so one would think that the file is being created. But apparently it isn't, because I get a FileNotFoundExeception when I try to load it using the EXACT SAME File class creation line.

Does anyone have any idea on what could be causing this?

SaveText is the saving function and LoadText is the loading function, obviously.

```
public void SaveText(View view)
{
        File CS_File = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "BLUH.txt");
        CS_File.mkdirs();
        try {
            CS_File.createNewFile();
            FileWriter CS_FileWriter = new FileWriter(CS_File); 
            EditText CS_EditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.createscreen_edittext);
            String CS_MessageTemp = CS_EditText.getText().toString();
            CS_FileWriter.write(CS_MessageTemp);
            CS_FileWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("WriteFile", "Error writing" + CS_File, e);
        }
        TextView CS_TestText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.createscreen_testtext);
        CS_TestText.setText(CS_File.toString());
    }
public void LoadText(View view)
    {
        File CS_File = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "BLUH.txt");
        String CS_Message = "";
        try {
            FileInputStream CS_FileInputS = new FileInputStream(CS_File);
            CS_FileInputS.read(CS_Message.getBytes(), 0, CS_Message.length());
            CS_FileInputS.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("LoadFile", "Error loading" + CS_File, e);
        }
        Intent INT_DisplayScreen = new Intent(this, ACT_DisplayScreen.class);
        INT_DisplayScreen.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, CS_Message);
        startActivity(INT_DisplayScreen);
    }
```

[The error dump.](http://pastebin.com/WzYUKWAb) (Full dump at link)

```
08-20 17:23:31.349: W/LoadFile(1399): Error loading/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/portalboat.concept/files/BLUH.txt
08-20 17:23:31.349: W/LoadFile(1399): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/portalboat.concept/files/BLUH.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-20 17:23:31.349: W/LoadFile(1399):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
08-20 17:23:31.349: W/LoadFile(1399):   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
08-20 17:23:31.349: W/LoadFile(1399):   at     portalboat.concept.ACT_CreateScreen.LoadText(ACT_CreateScreen.java:86)
08-20 17:23:31.349: W/LoadFile(1399):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 17:23:31.349: W/LoadFile(1399):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 17:23:31.349: W/LoadFile(1399):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3068)
08-20 17:23:31.349: W/LoadFile(1399):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3540)
08-20 17:23:31.349: W/LoadFile(1399):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14167)
08-20 17:23:31.349: W/LoadFile(1399):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
```

Comment: Post the code directly.

Comment: Does the app have write permissions?

Comment: can you put a println statement after "File CS_File = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "BLUH.txt");" in both your save and load methods that prints the absolute path of CS_FILE? Let me know if they are the same absolute paths.

Comment: If something throws within your try-block, `CS_FileWriter` will never be closed. You should put the `CS_FileWriter.close()` in a `finally` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using DMS to see if the file is created successfully.

Try the below to read file

```
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),filename);
        if (file !=null) {// reading file from SD card
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = "";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                // process line here
               }

            reader.close();
        }
```

As Roddy says remember to add write permission